# Change the behaviour of emph per environment

Tags: environments, emphasis

Is there redefine the way emph behaves in the `definition` environment?

Right now, since `definition` is in italics, emph just makes the text non-italic which is not enough to make it stand out. Is there a way to switch to be bold if and only if emph is used within the `definition` environment?

Comment: On modern LaTeX, I tend to use `\renewcommand\eminnershape{\itshape\bfseries}`, then each time `\emph` is used in an italic context, such as a definition or theorem, then it will be italic bold. If you only want it for `definition` then `etoolbox` has a feature where you can add stuff to the start of an environment, then just add my redef above to that. For details see the `etoolbox ` manual

Comment: Thank you! `\AtBeginEnvironment{definition}{\renewcommand\eminnershape{\itshape\bfseries}}` did the trick

Comment: A further trick you might be interested in: If you use `enumitem` to configure your lists (recommended) then the above feature can also be used to add a default list configuration in theorem like envs. Say to ensure that `enumerate` by default use (i), (ii), etc within theorems. Then you do not have to add those manually each time (and have to check them all to make sure you were consistent)

Comment: @daleif Would you like to write up an answer for this?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On modern LaTeX systems you can use

```
\renewcommand\eminnershape{\itshape\bfseries}
```

to change the way `\emph` behaves in an italic context.

If you only want it for `definitions`, include the `etoolbox` package and

```
 \AtBeginEnvironment{definition}{\renewcommand\eminnershape{\‌​itshape\bfseries}}
```