# Changing the behaviour of `\emph'` inside an environment

Tags: environments, emphasis

I want to change the behaviour of `\emph{}` command inside definitions to be bold rather than italic.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315058/change-the-behaviour-of-emph-per-environment) has a nice and elegant solution for the problem (or so it seems).
It just doesn't work for me.

The reason is that the answer refers to the command

```
\renewcommand\eminnershape{\itshape\bfseries}
```

triggers an error: `! LaTeX Error: \eminnershape undefined.`

Now, there is something that caught my attention: in the answer, it says "On modern LaTeX systems you can use" before the command line above.
So maybe my LaTeX distribution is not modern enough
(I believe this is TeX Live 2010, because that's written in the beginning of the console; by the way, I'm using TeXShop 2.46).

**Question:** Supposing that this is a problem with my archaic distribution, is there a reasonable solution for this?

Here is a minimal (?) running example

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\textsc{Theorem}}
%\renewcommand\eminnershape{\bfseries}
\begin{document}
Here's my \emph{message} to the world:
\begin{theorem}
This is \emph{my} theorem.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try replacing `renewcommand` with `\newcommand`?

Comment: That is a very old latex installation. If possible, install a newer one. If you cannot load the fixltx2e package (I think that is the name). It will define eminnershape. Nowadays it us in the latex kernel.

Comment: Also, on a modern system you can use the etoolbox package to inject the redefinition into certain environments. Done that for many docs

Comment: @Bernard With `\newcommand` it gives error.

Comment: @daleif With the `fixltx2e` package the minimal example I presented works fine, thanks a lot! However, in the full example it doesn't do anything, but that is another subject I'll have to research carefully. Thank you both.

Comment: Well it turns out it works, for theorems, lemmas, corollaries... environments with the same theorem style as theorems; for those defined after `\theoremstyle{definition}`, including definitions, which is the one for which I wanted this, it does nothing. I'll have to see if I understand why it makes a difference. But maybe I'll really have to update the installation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestions made by Daleif I added the package `fixltx2e` and got rid of the previous error and everything seemed to work.
However, when I added a `definition` environment, I noticed that `\emph{}` was still using italics in this environment (and bold in the `theorem` environment).
So I proceeded to use the package `etoolbox` and replaced the command line
`\renewcommand\eminnershape{\bfseries}` with
`\AtBeginEnvironment{definition}{\renewcommand\eminnershape{\bfseries}}`
which also didn't work (although it works also fine with the `theorem` environment).
Finally, noticing that in this last command line we're inside the `definition` environment, I though that we don't need `eminnershape` since it is for all instances of `em` that occur there.
As a wild guess, I replaced `eminnershape` with `em` and it worked.

Now I'm not very confident of this approach because I'm afraid it is not very solid (even though it's working, and that's not only with this minimal example).
So if someone reads this and knows better than me, please tell me about the issues that may arise.

Here's a full working example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,fixltx2e,etoolbox}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\AtBeginEnvironment{definition}{\renewcommand\em{\bfseries}}

\begin{document}
Here's my \emph{message} to the world:
    \begin{definition}
        This is \emph{my} definition.
    \end{definition}
    \begin{theorem}
        And this is \emph{my} theorem.
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image]

Comment: `\eminnershape` is used *when you are in an italic context*. As your definition is written upright it does nothing there. So redefining \em is needed. But personally I wouldn't use bold for general emphazing. It looks very bad at the end.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer bold italic is usually fine, if the context is italic, that is how I use it. Emphasizing using non-bold is not quite visible enough

Comment: @daleif: I agree that with italic is it probably needed -- I think I used a semibold here once -- but the definition example uses upright font and I loath texts with 5-10 black spots spread over the pages (and I just looked in the mathastext documentation and think I loath color spots too - I can't read texts where my eyes always spring to such a spot).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer agreed, that is normally also what I advise to authors

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: thank you. The bold emphasizing is only to be used in definitions. This is because italic doesn't stand out enough when we're looking for the definition of something, and the concepts defined in definition environments are supposed to be more important. At least this is my interpretation and, anyway, this is the re-visitation of an old work, and I decided to stick to the original authors decision (at least for now). But I'll have to look at that semibold, which I didn't know about. Thanks again.

Comment: Then I would suggest that you define a `\strongemph` command and use this where you think it necessary. Easier and better semantic .